# Find the longest file name

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find, command

I have to find the symbolic link which contains the longest folder name in a folder full of symbolic links. So far I have this:

```
find <folder> -type l -printf "%l\n"
```

I was wondering if there's any way to save the folder names while searching, something like this pseudo code:

```
if [length > max]
{
  max = length
  var = link
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by _longest folder name_? Can you give some example and expect outcome?

Comment: When you change your requirements, you should ask a separate question instead. Otherwise, that invalidates all the already given answers (which may still be useful for people having similar requirements as your original ones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /path/to/base -type l | awk -F/ 'BEGIN {maxlength = 0; longest = "" } length( $NF ) > maxlength { maxlength = length( $NF ); longest = $NF } END { print "longest was", longest, "at", maxlength, "characters." }'
```

To make the `awk` more readable:

```
BEGIN {
   maxlength = 0
   longest = ""
} 

length( $NF ) > maxlength { 
   maxlength = length( $NF )
   longest = $NF
} 
END { 
   print "longest was", longest, "at", maxlength, "characters." 
}
```

`awk` is great at dealing with delimited data.  Since paths are delimited by `/`s, we use that as the field separator (with the `-F` switch), track the longest name we've seen with a `longest` variable, and its length in the `maxlength` variable.  Some care and feeding to make the output sane if no links are found I shall leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Future readers.  This will give you the longest name.. of the "short-file-name.txt" for example.  If you remove the -F/  "flag".. you can get the longest overall full path name .. like "/mypath1/mypath2/my-file-name.txt" for example.  Thanks DopeGhoti.  (and for provided enough details to look at the -F switch in detail)

Comment: To be fair, the question _was_ longest **file name**, not longest **path** (:  Glad my answer was clear enough for you to adapt for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
by_link_depth() {
  zstat -A REPLY +link -- ${1-$REPLY}
  REPLY=${REPLY//[^\/]}
}
```

defines a function that returns the slashes in the target of the symlink, then you can use it as a sorting method for your globs:

```
ls -ld -- **/*(D@O+by_link_depth[1])
```

Would list the symlink (`@`), including hidden ones (`D`) with  the deepest target (`O+by_link_depth`, reverse-sorts by link depth, and `[1]` selects the first).

Here in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ ls -ld -- **/*(D@O+by_link_depth[1])
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Oct  9 03:08 mptopdf -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/context/perl/mptopdf.pl
$ ls -lUd -- **/*(D@O+by_link_depth[1,3])
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Oct  9 03:08 mptopdf -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/context/perl/mptopdf.pl*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Oct  9 03:09 pkfix-helper -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/pkfix-helper/pkfix-helper*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 60 Oct  9 03:09 mkjobtexmf -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/mkjobtexmf/mkjobtexmf.pl*
```

If you only care about the max-depth link  target and not the symlink that points to it, you can run `zstat +link` instead of `ls -ld` on that symlink, or you could instead define a `resolve` and `by_depth` function:

```
resolve() zstat -A REPLY +link -- ${1-$REPLY}
by_depth() REPLY=${REPLY//[^\/]}
```

and:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(D@O+by_depth+resolve[1])
```

Where `+resolve` translates the symlink to its target for the glob expansion, and `O+by_depth` reverse-sorts by depth.

With `bash` (though the code below is in no way `bash` specific) and GNU utilities (your `-printf` is already GNU-specific), you could get something approaching with:

```
find . -type l -printf '%l\0%p\0' | gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' -F / '
   {n = NF; getline; if (n > max) {max = n; file = $0}}
   END {if (max) print file}' | xargs -r0 ls -ld
```

Or for the deepest target only:

```
find . -type l -printf '%l\0' | gawk -v RS='\0' -F / '
   NF > max {max = NF; target = $0}
   END {if (max) print target}'
```